# CakePHP Model::create and Model::save() performance in loop

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am at CakePHP 2.3.4 and PHP 5.5 with MySQL running on my Ubuntu server. I have loop like this:

```
foreach($notification_group['User'] as $notification_user) {
    // Do something
    $this->set($notification);
    $this->Notification->create();
    $this->Notification->save($notification);  // 0.4 seconds per iteration
}

// Do same something
$this->set($notification);
$this->Notification->create();
$this->Notification->save($notification);  // Less than 0.1 seconds
```

In the loop, each iteration would take 0.4 seconds to complete. But the create and save method outside the loop only take (way) less than 0.1 seconds to finish. The loop overhead should not be a problem.

Why it takes so much longer to do a basic insert in a loop? How to improve it? Thanks!

Update 1: I have tried comment out the create and save methods in the loop and it turns out the loop doesn't have too much overhead at all. 
I would like to know why this performance hit is happening before I try saveMany() or other methods.

Update 2: I have tried saveMany() to save an array of notification in a single shot. Here is the code snippet:

```
$notification_array = array();

// Save notificaions
foreach($notification_group['User'] as $notification_user) {
    $notification = null;
    // Do something
    $this->set($notification);
    array_push($notification_array, $notification);
    // $this->Notification->create();
    // $this->Notification->save($notification);
}

if (!empty($notification_array)) {
    $this->Notification->saveMany($notification_array);
}
```

The performance is the same as using create and save in the loop - 0.4 seconds per iteration/record to save. If I comment out the saveMany(), the performance hit is gone.

Update 3: I am not at NotificationController. I load the notification model at the beginning of my function:

```
$this->loadModel('Notification');
```

And the loop is the first one who uses the notification model. Is the lazy-loading mechanism responsible for the performance hit? How to avoid it?

Comment: This would be better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: what is $notification inside loop? it also incurs the ($notification_group['User'] as $notification_user) overhead that your non-loop is not timing? also php is a dog for performance

Comment: you can use `saveAll` or `saveMany` as per your need. Avoid loops for inserting data. Just rearrange your array according to the format this will improve the performance

Comment: if the amt to be inserted is relatively managable, do a SINGLE insert against an array

Comment: @DrewPierce $notification is an array that has user data (only a couple string and int elements). The loop overhead can be ignore as I timed that as well.

Comment: so the exact three lines have different time over a major amount of data and not subject to voodoo or other processes that happen to be running that slow your computer down